# How to do the same in rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Sample Rails 3 code for ActiveSupport

```
set_callback :save, :before, :before_meth
set_callback :save, :after,  :after_meth, :if => :condition
set_callback :save, :around, lambda { |r| stuff; result = yield; stuff }
```

can anyone suggest how to perform this operation in rails 2 since there is no set_callback method i need to perform some operation just before a method call in rails 2?

Comment: I realize that this is maybe beside the point, and possibly not an option, but Rails 2 will be dropped from maintenance (including security updates) as soon as Rails 4 is officially released, per the maintenance policy. If you plan to keep this app around you'll need to migrate it to Rails 3 at some point.

Comment: `define_callbacks :before_something, :after_something?` ?

Comment: we are planning to migrate soon but right now i need to find some way to do this....

Comment: @ted can you please elaborate...

Answer (score 1):

Use before_save and after_save. http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/#M001840